# Can you award a bounty without accepting the answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, bounty

What happens if there are partial answers to a bounty question. Can you award a bounty without accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. Here is the proof:

> **Reward existing answer**
>
> One **or more** of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

So at least answer is not accepted!